# Check which Activity loads a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a way to check which activity loads a fragment from within the fragment? I have a user profile fragment which is loaded from 2 different activities but only one passes a value in, so when getting values from the bundle when the fragment loads from the activity that doesn't pass a value throws a nullpointerexception. Or is there a better way to pass the value into the fragment so the fragment can get the value only when loaded from this specific activity?

Comment: Maybe, you just need two newInstance() methods inside your fragment. One with a parameter, another without a parameter. After that in onCreate method of your fragment you can just read parameter if it has been passed. After that inside your fragment just check if the parameter is not null where it is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two static methods (also known as **Static Factory Methods**) which returns instances of your `Fragment` with the parameters you want to pass with bundle like the following code:

```
private static final String BUNDLE_VALUE_KEY = "value";

@NonNull
public static YourFragment newInstance() {
   return new YourFragment();
}

@NonNull
public static YourFragment newInstance(@NonNull String yourValue) {
   final YourFragment instance = new YourFragment();
   final Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString(BUNDLE_VALUE_KEY,yourValue);
   instance.setArguments(args);
   return instance;
}
```

In your `Activity` which you want to pass the value you can use:

```
final YourFragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance(value);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
          .commit();
```

In other `Activity` you can use:

```
final YourFragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
        .commit();
```

And in `onCreate` method of your `Fragment` you can check arguments and init your value like the following code:

```
final Bundle args = getArguments();
if(args != null){
      yourValue = args.getString(BUNDLE_VALUE_KEY,null);
}
```

So if your `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity` which passes data you'll have it. If the `Fragment` is attached to other `Activity` you'll have the **initial value** (in the example it's `null`)

Or you can check the instance of `Activity` which `Fragment` gets attached. (Not best practice)

```
if(getActivity() instanceof YourActivityWhichPassesData){
   yourValue = getArguments().getString(BUNDLE_VALUE_KEY,null);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do this check in your fragment:

```
if(getActivity() instanceof SomeActivity){
//do something
}
```

You can also cast the `getActivity()` call if you are sure which Activity it is (and then call methods from that Activity).